# Artin’s theorem on induced representations and the kernel

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, and let $X$ be a family of subgroups of $G$ closed under conjugation and under passage to subgroups. Suppose further that $G$ is the union of the elements of $X,$ and denote by $R(G)$ the representation ring. By Artin’s theorem, we have a surjective map 
$$Ind: \oplus_{H \in X} \mathbb{Q} \otimes R(H) \rightarrow \mathbb{Q} \otimes R(G),$$ given by taking the induced character and extending by linearity. I will now define two special classes of elements in the source of this map.

**Elements of Class 1:** Let $H,H’ \in X, H’ \subset H,$ and let $\psi’ \in R(H’).$ Let $\psi = Ind_{H’}^H \psi’.$ Then elements of class $1$ are of the form $\psi-\psi’.$

**Elements of class 2:**
 Let $H \in X, s \in G$ and set $H^s = sHs^{-1}.$ Let $\psi \in R(H),$ and define $\psi^s \in R(H^s)$ by $\psi^s(shs^{-1})= \psi(h).$ Then elements of class $2$ are of the form $\psi-\psi’.$

It is easy to see that all elements of class $1$ and $2$ lie in the kernel of the map $Ind.$ I want to prove that in fact, the kernel is generated by elements of class $1$ and $2.$ The hint I have seem is that one should base change go $\mathbb{C},$ and then use duality. It is then claimed that one is reduced to proving that if for every $H \in X$ one has a class function $f_H$ satisfying restriction snd conjugation conditions as above, then there exists a class function $f$ on $G$ restricting to $f_H$ for all $X.$.

I supppse we should use Frobenius reciprocity in some clever way, but I do not see how the statement reduces to what I just claimed, so I would appreciate help, or full solutions.